# Ubuntu 20.04 Font giltch on GNOME

Tags: gnome, 20.04, fonts

I've ran into a problem some time ago, and hadn't be able to fix it myself or through solutions on the net, so I will expose it here, in hope someone knows the answer...

So, since my upgrade from 19.10 to 20.04, all GNOME-related fonts (notifications, right click on the desktop, quick access menu, applications rack) are glitched on specific letters (see attached picture). I'm fairly new to the linux/ubuntu ecosystem and can't possibly recall everything I've tried, so all suggestions welcome !

Thanks in advance !

[image: glitched right click on desktop]

**EDIT :**
I've tried a few things to fix the problem. One thing that seems to work is to switch the system language to English.

Another fix is to order a total restart of GNOME with Alt+F12 then 'r'. However this method does not always work, and sometimes introduces other odd glitches in the interface. Moreover it seems only temporary, as the font glitches come back again some time later.

[image: Odd glitches in the interface...]

I should point out that I did not have any of these problems before updating to 20.04, so maybe is it due to a broken package dependency ?

Comment: I had those glitches on Ubuntu 16.04. But after reinstalling the OS it went away. Other than this glitch, sometimes my pointer would get stuck to the edges of the screen. But reinstalling fixed those issues.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that reinstalling ubuntu would fix the problem, but I would prefer to avoid such extremity if I can. If not, that's what I will probably end up doing... Glad it's not tied to my computer, at least !